# Woocommerce - Billing / shipping address doesn't update in My Account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing a little weird problem: when I change the billing or shipping address inside My Account screen, the address seems to have changed, however after refresh the page, the old address remains there and I look at the admin and check that anything was changed.

Have you ever seen that issue before? My theme still uses Woocommerce 1.6.4 because we're working on a new theme development and we can't update WC yet.

Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. The problem was the WP Super Cache Plugin. The document below on the Woocommerce website explains why this happens. The cart, my account, and checkout page need to stay dynamic since they display information specific to the current customer.

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/

If you aren't using a caching plugin, try clearing out your browser cache. If that doesn't fix the issue, I would revert back to the basics. Updating Woocommerce would be highly recommended, but in your case, I would disable any new plugins you have added. Since you are using an old version of Woocommerce, any new plugins added could be creating a conflict. I hope that helps!

Comment: Good point! I worked for an agency and that customer actually still is a customer of that agency. The owner sometimes gets some extra job and gives me that account to solve some issues. I remember that I had installed a cache plugin however I didn't remember about. I will notice the owner about how long I will take to investigate and after payment I buy you a beer! Thanks man.